# Async - parallel() with functions dynamic array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, async.js

I am using the excellent caolan "async" module for nodejs:

I have this code:

```
exports.manageComments = function(req, res) {
    var toDeleteIds = [];
    var deleteFunctions = [];
    if (req.body.doDelete) {
        toDeleteIds = req.body.doDelete;
    }
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < toDeleteIds.length; i++ ) {
        var deleteFunction = function(callback) {
            var id = toDeleteIds[i];
            console.log(id);
            Comment.findOne({_id:id}, function(err, found) {            
                if (!err) found.remove(callback);
            });
        }
        deleteFunctions.push(deleteFunction);
    }
    async.parallel(
        deleteFunctions,
        function(err,results) {
            exports.comments(req, res); //render a view
        }
    );
};
```

My array contains two elements but console.log() keeps telling me "undefined".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is with:

```
    var deleteFunction = function(callback) {
        var id = toDeleteIds[i];
```

because at the time each callback function is executed, `i` will have the same value as `toDeleteIds.length`. A closure doesn't "trap" the value that an outer variable had at the time it was *created*; it "traps" a reference to whatever value the outer variable has at the time it's *executed* (which in this case won't be until well after your `for` loop has finished.

In order to "trap" the value of `i` at the time you create your callback function, you need to make `i` a parameter of a function that you call to create your callback function. You need something like

```
    var deleteFunction = makeDeleteFunction(i, callback);
```

And then create a separate function outside the callback:

```
function makeDeleteFunction(i, callback) {
    return function(callback) {
        var id = toDeleteIds[i];
        console.log(id);
        Comment.findOne({_id:id}, function(err, found){            
            if (!err) found.remove(callback);
        });
     };
}
```

Comment: I had this suspect! You are really good at explaining it! Thank you 1000 times! :D I'll accept the answer later, let me first try it!

Answer (score 4):

ebohlman has correctly identified the problem. However I still think creating an array of closures is **hugely inefficient** and unnecessary. Here's shorter, easier code to achieve the same with a single function:

```js
exports.manageComments = function(req, res) {
    var toDeleteIds = [];
    if (req.body.doDelete) {
        toDeleteIds = req.body.doDelete;
    }

    var deleteFunction = function(id, callback) {
        console.log(id);
        Comment.findOne({_id:id}, function(err, found) {            
            if (!err) found.remove(callback);
        });
    }

    async.forEach(toDeleteIds, deleteFunction, function(err,results) {
        exports.comments(req, res); //render a view
    });
};
```

Comment: Finally I adopted your solution, thank you very much! However this question was just to know how the "closures" mechanism works.

Comment: @zzen "results" aren't passed at the end unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this another way, if you don't need to fire the Mongoose `remove` middleware on each `Comment` doc being removed, you can remove all identified comments in one go:

```
Comment.remove({_id: {$in: toDeleteIds}}, function(err, numRemoved) {
    exports.comments(req, res); //render a view        
}
```

Comment: you're right but I prefer doing single updates this time, just for learning purpose. Thank you.